# How to determine which url is user coming from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel framework and there are a lot of situations where I have to redirect back to previous pages. I did it through a lazy method of storing the current url in a session and then redirected using it.

I want to know if there any any possible and faster method to redirect back to page we came from.

something like in controller `return redirect()->back();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use

`return redirect()->back();`

it works fine, also if you have to send back with something you can do like this

`return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');`

See this 
http://laraveldaily.com/all-about-redirects-in-laravel-5/
for about redirecting

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user back to the page from which he is coming using this.

```
use Redirect;
return Redirect::back();
```

It will redirect him back to that page.